# How to make "%" wildcard match targets containing the equal sign?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The makefile wildcard system doesn't seem to match targets if they contain the equal sign. Is there a way to work around this deficiency? Some flag or setting or rule to escape the equal sign? I know I can just not use the equal sign but I'd prefer to fix this idiosyncrasy of make if possible.

Here's an example of what I mean

```
$ cat Makefile
all:
    echo Dummy target
b_%:
    echo $@

$ make b_c=1
  echo Dummy Target
$ make b_c1
  echo b_c1
```

The first make command does not match `b_%` even though it should. I also wasn't able to find documentation for exactly what is supposed to be matched by the % wildcard. Any pointers? My make version is

```
$ make --version                                               
GNU Make 3.81         
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.                                                                                                             
This program built for i386-apple-darwin10.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not with the `%` syntax, but with the fact that [any command-line argument with an equals sign in it is interpreted as a variable assignment](https://www.gnu.org/s/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html).

You should find that if you add the dependency `all: b_c=1`, then `make all` will generate the file just fine.

There are restrictions on what file names you can use with `make` -- they can't contain spaces or newlines, and e.g. backslashes are problematic, too (though not completely impossible to accommodate for simple use cases).

If you absolutely have to have a file named like this, my suggested workaround would be to use a different name internally, and then symlink it to the external name as the last step of the `make` recipe.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs. I switched from `=` to `~` as a workaround.

Comment: Relevant line from the link `Any target in the makefile may be specified as a goal (unless it starts with ‘-’ or contains an ‘=’, in which case it will be parsed as a switch or variable definition, respectively).`